# how to find nearest point in a large grid fast

Tags: r

I have a grid composed of 1k points (long and lat) `grid`

I have another list of 10k points (also long and lat) `pts`

I want to find which grid point each value in pts is closest to.

I have a brute force algorithm, but is slow:

```
d=NULL
for( i in 1:nrow(pts){
    for(j in 1:nrow(grid){
        d=d,distHaversine(pts[i,2:3],grid[j,2:3]))
}
}
m1=data.frame(matrix(d,ncol=nrow(grid),byrow=1)
c=apply(m,2,which.min)
```

is there a way to speed this up, and the brute force is rather slow and tedius.

I am using R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distHaversine` is vectorized, so you only need one loop. And you certainly don't need to store all the distances, just keep the min each iteration if that's all you want.

```
c = numeric(nrow(pts))
for( i in 1:nrow(pts){
  c[i] = which.min(distHaversine(pts[i, 2:3], grid[, 2:3])
}
```

The above should work and be substantially faster. If you 
still want to go faster, you could look at doing the iterations in parallel.